# Mostrar imagen según horario

Tags: javascript, html

Hace un tiempo armé un script en base a otro y pude mostrar una imagen según la hora y se actualizaba correctamente de manera automática. Ahora quise usar el mismo script con algunas modificaciones para lograr que dependiendo si el usuario ingresa desde una pc o un móvil me muestre una imagen determinada en una hora específica. Esto sirve para la programación de mi radio online. El script funciona y se actualiza la imágen si ingreso desde móvil, pero si ingreso desde PC, la imágen no se actualiza, salvo que presione f5 o ingrese a determinada hora, aparecerá la imagen que corresponde. Pero el problema es por ejemplo si ingreso a las 18:50 y se hacen las 19 hs , tendriá que cambiarse sola la imagen a las 19hs, desde móvil, lo hace pero en PC no, algo estaría fallando, comparto script. La falla está en setInterval de cambie_imagenn, lo curioso que este setInterval si funciona fuera del If. funciona para un array de imagenes, pero cuando uso las dos solo funciona el SetInterval del Else (cambie_imagenncelu). Soy novato.

```js
<script>
      const fullwidth = document.getElementById("fullwidth");

      if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 480px)").matches) {
        fullwidth.innerHTML = '<img  src=""  id="imagen_cambiantee" style="float: left; width: 100%;" />';
       
function cambie_imagenn () {
  
 let dd = new Date(); // fecha y hora del cliente
 thisday= dd.getUTCDay();  // día de la semana UTC
  let la_horaa = dd.getUTCHours();  // Hora UTC
 
var list_imagesspc;

if(thisday == "0"){ // SI ES domingo
list_imagesspc =  ["https://i.ibb.co/54JzYPR/BUENprog.png", "https://i.ibb.co/dk6FHTN/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-45.png","https://i.ibb.co/dk6FHTN/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-45.png","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/vkZSXrb/aedionauri-1.png"]

} else if (thisday == "1") { // SI ES LUNES
list_imagesspc = ["https://i.ibb.co/nssfRZT/mcprog.png", "https://i.ibb.co/GTFtDZZ/romaprogr1123.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/yqNJ9x1/CARPROGR1.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg"]

} else if (thisday == "2") { // SI ES MARTES
list_imagesspc =  ["https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png", "https://i.ibb.co/VL5Tg8X/ameliee.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png"]

} else if (thisday == "3") { // SI ES MIERCOLES
list_imagesspc =  ["https://i.ibb.co/7KMr5QW/missmonique11.jpg", "https://i.ibb.co/ZWg1n6t/NINA-KRAVIk.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/D52jCJP/deborahh11.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZWg1n6t/NINA-KRAVIk.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/ZWg1n6t/NINA-KRAVIk.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ","https://i.ibb.co/ZWg1n6t/NINA-KRAVIk.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png"]

} else if (thisday == "4") { // SI ES JUEVES
list_imagesspc = ["https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png", "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZWg1n6t/NINA-KRAVIk.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/mHK3sQ1/Copia-de-ABRILLIVEPROGRA.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZWg1n6t/NINA-KRAVIk.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png"]

} else if (thisday == "5") { // / SI ES VIERNES
list_imagesspc = ["https://i.ibb.co/7bSkc4F/cristianmadridprog22345.jpg", "https://i.ibb.co/mHK3sQ1/Copia-de-ABRILLIVEPROGRA.png","https://i.ibb.co/svBCwJK/RAINPROG.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/b36NhVx/PATRIKprograma113.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/FwD0718/portadaprog.png","https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png","https://i.ibb.co/FwD0718/portadaprog.png","https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png","https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png","https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png"," https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/kKQCZj4/tonyprog-1.png","https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png","https://i.ibb.co/4ZVzBgn/emaprog.png"]

} else if (thisday == "6") { // SI ES SABADO
list_imagesspc = ["https://i.ibb.co/QXpMpFW/fernandoprogra.png", "https://i.ibb.co/swBy5Fb/tonynoelive1.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/FhB1rjb/daviaklive.png"]
}

 
  var imagen_seleccionadaa = list_imagesspc[la_horaa];
window.document.getElementById("imagen_cambiantee") .src=imagen_seleccionadaa;

}
 
   cambie_imagenn();
setInterval ("cambie_imagenn()", 60000 ); // Esta linea hace que cada 60 segundo cheque si cambio de hora, y asi camibar de imagen 

      } else {
        fullwidth.innerHTML = '<img  src=""  id="imagen_cambianteecelu" style="float: left; width: 100%;" />';
        function cambie_imagenncelu (){
  
 let ddcelu = new Date(); // fecha y hora del cliente
 thisday= ddcelu.getUTCDay();  // día de la semana UTC
  let la_horaacelu = ddcelu.getUTCHours();  // Hora UTC
  
var list_imagesscelu;

if(thisday == "0"){ // SI ES domingo
list_imagesscelu =  ["https://i.ibb.co/vZDtwKd/edgardo-480-450-px.png", "https://i.ibb.co/dk6FHTN/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-45.png","https://i.ibb.co/dk6FHTN/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-45.png","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/6P2wbRh/aedion-480-450-px.png"]

} else if (thisday == "1") { // SI ES LUNES
list_imagesscelu = ["https://i.ibb.co/GWvMSB7/mc-480-450-px.png", "https://i.ibb.co/8mScyqm/roma2-480-450-px.png","https://i.ibb.co/SPJYZBS/carlos-480-450-px-1.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg"]

} else if (thisday == "2") { // SI ES MARTES
list_imagesscelu =  ["https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png", "https://i.ibb.co/VL5Tg8X/ameliee.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/2YM7jGy/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-49.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png"]

} else if (thisday == "3") { // SI ES MIERCOLES
list_imagesscelu =  ["https://i.ibb.co/7KMr5QW/missmonique11.jpg", "https://i.ibb.co/ZWg1n6t/NINA-KRAVIk.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/D52jCJP/deborahh11.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/hKWvcXc/EMANUEL2023-480-450-px-3.png","https://i.ibb.co/37TMS3V/EMANUEL2023-480-450-px-4.png","https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png","https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png","https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png","https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png","https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png","https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png","https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png"]

} else if (thisday == "4") { // SI ES JUEVES
list_imagesscelu = ["https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png", "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png","https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png","https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png"]

} else if (thisday == "5") { // / SI ES VIERNES
list_imagesscelu = ["https://i.ibb.co/7bSkc4F/cristianmadridprog22345.jpg", "https://i.ibb.co/mHK3sQ1/Copia-de-ABRILLIVEPROGRA.png","https://i.ibb.co/wry0KBy/rain-480-450-px.png","https://i.ibb.co/b36NhVx/PATRIKprograma113.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/FwD0718/portadaprog.png","https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png","https://i.ibb.co/FwD0718/portadaprog.png","https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png","https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png","https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png"," https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/kKQCZj4/tonyprog-1.png","https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png","https://i.ibb.co/37TMS3V/EMANUEL2023-480-450-px-4.png"]

} else if (thisday == "6") { // SI ES SABADO
list_imagesscelu = ["https://i.ibb.co/25vQXb6/fernando-480-450-px.png", "https://i.ibb.co/swBy5Fb/tonynoelive1.png","https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg","https://i.ibb.co/hFfkKK1/daviak-480-450-px.png"]
}
 var imagen_seleccionadaacelu = list_imagesscelu[la_horaacelu];
window.document.getElementById("imagen_cambianteecelu") .src=imagen_seleccionadaacelu;
}
   cambie_imagenncelu();
setInterval ("cambie_imagenncelu()", 60000 ); // Esta linea hace que cada 60 segundo cheque si cambio de hora, y asi camibar de imagen   
 
}  
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo este código, basándome en tu código aplico refactor, han cambiado varias cosas, entre ellas tenemos las tareas del algoritmo divididas por funciones, te dejo comentada cada función, espero te sirva, saludos :D

```js
    // 1 - Obtenemos la fecha actual, día y hora
let date = new Date(),
    currentNumberDay = date.getUTCDay(),
    currentHourDay = date.getUTCHours();

    // 2 - Declaramos un objeto con una prop por día, c/u con sus respectivas imágenes por hora
const customImagesPC = {
    "0": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/vZDtwKd/edgardo-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/dk6FHTN/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-45.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/dk6FHTN/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-45.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6P2wbRh/aedion-480-450-px.png"
    ],
    "1": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/GWvMSB7/mc-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/8mScyqm/roma2-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/SPJYZBS/carlos-480-450-px-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg"
    ],
    "2": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/VL5Tg8X/ameliee.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/2YM7jGy/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-49.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png"
    ],
    "3": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/7KMr5QW/missmonique11.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZWg1n6t/NINA-KRAVIk.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/D52jCJP/deborahh11.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/hKWvcXc/EMANUEL2023-480-450-px-3.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/37TMS3V/EMANUEL2023-480-450-px-4.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png"
    ],
    "4": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png"
    ],
    "5": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/7bSkc4F/cristianmadridprog22345.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/mHK3sQ1/Copia-de-ABRILLIVEPROGRA.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/wry0KBy/rain-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/b36NhVx/PATRIKprograma113.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/FwD0718/portadaprog.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/FwD0718/portadaprog.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      " https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/kKQCZj4/tonyprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/37TMS3V/EMANUEL2023-480-450-px-4.png"
    ],
    "6": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/25vQXb6/fernando-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/swBy5Fb/tonynoelive1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/hFfkKK1/daviak-480-450-px.png"
    ]
  }

   // Aquí solo reemplaza tus imagenes que vas a poner si es movil
const customImagesMovil = {
    "0": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/vZDtwKd/edgardo-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/dk6FHTN/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-45.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/dk6FHTN/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-45.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6P2wbRh/aedion-480-450-px.png"
    ],
    "1": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/GWvMSB7/mc-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/8mScyqm/roma2-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/SPJYZBS/carlos-480-450-px-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg"
    ],
    "2": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/VL5Tg8X/ameliee.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/2YM7jGy/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-49.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png"
    ],
    "3": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/7KMr5QW/missmonique11.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZWg1n6t/NINA-KRAVIk.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/D52jCJP/deborahh11.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/hKWvcXc/EMANUEL2023-480-450-px-3.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/37TMS3V/EMANUEL2023-480-450-px-4.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png"
    ],
    "4": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png"
    ],
    "5": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/7bSkc4F/cristianmadridprog22345.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/mHK3sQ1/Copia-de-ABRILLIVEPROGRA.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/wry0KBy/rain-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/b36NhVx/PATRIKprograma113.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/FwD0718/portadaprog.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/FwD0718/portadaprog.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      " https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/kKQCZj4/tonyprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/37TMS3V/EMANUEL2023-480-450-px-4.png"
    ],
    "6": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/25vQXb6/fernando-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/swBy5Fb/tonynoelive1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/hFfkKK1/daviak-480-450-px.png"
    ]
  }

    /* 3 - Esta función solamente obtendrá los valores de la propiedad [X] que la pasemos por parámetro
    * Accede a la prop 0,1,2,3 según sea el caso
    * Accede a la posición de la prop 0,1,2 etc para obtener el nombre de imagen por hora.
    * NOTA: Se agrega una validación para saber de donde tomar los recursos, si es movil o no.
    */
let getImage = (numberDay, currentHour, isMovil) =>{
    const getImageByDay = isMovil ? customImagesMovil[numberDay] : customImagesPC[numberDay] 
    return getImageByDay[currentHour]; 
}

    /* 4 - Esta función cada X tiempo (60 seg) ejecutará la función getImage() para obtener la url
    *      y mediante un callback (Función que se ejecuta después de haberse ejecutado una anteriormente)
    *      devolverá la url.
    */
let executeInterval = (isMovil, callback) =>{
    setInterval(() =>{
        callback(getImage(currentNumberDay, currentHourDay, isMovil))
    }, 2000); // Cambiar timer a 60 seg.
}

    /* 5 - En este punto seteamos al cargar la página una imagen según la hora y día, 
    *      seguido ejecutamos la función executeInterval() pasando como parámetro una función para recuperar el valor del intervalo
    *      y setearlo cada x tiempo al atributo src de tu tag imagen.
    */
let setImage = (isMovil) => {
    document.getElementById("fullwidth").src = getImage(currentNumberDay, currentHourDay, isMovil)

    executeInterval(isMovil, newUrl => {
        console.log("New URL and TAG", document.getElementById("fullwidth").src = newUrl)
        document.getElementById("fullwidth").src = newUrl
    })
}
    /* 6 - Aquí solo hacemos comparación para saber si estamos en un movil o no, posterior a eso ejecutamos la funcion setImage()
     * pasando como parametro un bool (true o false) segun sea el caso, si es true obtiene las imagagenes del objeto customImagesMovil,
     * caso contrario si es false obtiene la imagen de customImagesPC
     */

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)  || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {
    // console.log("Phone");
    setImage(true)
} else {
    // console.log("No Phone");
    setImage(false)
}
```

```html
<img id="fullwidth"></img>
```

Comment: esta bueno, pero por ejemplo, si entra desde el móvil es otro array, tiene imagenes diferentes para el móvil,estoy aprendiendo, donde pondria el otro array? y por ejemplo en el código que porporcioné empieza desde las 21 hs en adelante, este funcionaría igual? usando UTC.

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta agregando un nuevo objeto con los recursos para teléfono móvil, de la misma manera una validación para saber si los recursos serán obtenidos del objeto pc o móvil, solo cambia las imágenes que vas a poner en el objeto móvil, ya que es una copia del primero, este código empieza desde la hora en que ejecutes el script, por ejemplo, ahora son las 8:12 hr mx, día 4 de la semana.

Comment: gracias, el código estaría funcionando, pero me pasa lo mismo que el que brindé, por ejemplo si el usuario escucha la radio de la web desde las 14:50 en la que esta la foto del dj1.jpg, se hacen las 15 hs y debería aparecer automáticamente la foto del dj de las 15 hs dj2.jpg, sin necesidad de recargar la web. En ambos códigos debo presionar f5 o recargar la web para que aparezca la nueva foto. Si no lo hago sigue apareciendo la misma foto de las 14 hs. Quizas habría que reajustar el setInterval. Lo raro que en el código que brindé lo hace pero sólo en la foto de móvil.

Comment: Qué podría ser que la imagen no se actualiza automáticamente en la transcición de hora?

Comment: Agregué un nombre a la función del script y fuera de la función un setInterval (nombre de la función,5000); logro que la imagen se actualice en la transcicion horaria pero queda parpapadeando, alguna sugerencia? gracias

Answer (score 1):

Intente colocar el setInterval que usaba en el código publicado en la pregunta, en tu respuesta y la imagen logra cambiarse automáticamente en la transición horaria, por ejemplo si el usuario esta en la web a las 20:55 y se hacen las 21, se cambia la imagen automáticamente, sin necesidad de recargar la web , pero la imagen parpadea, junto con la anterior, quizás es porque coloqué en el lugar donde no corresponde el setInterval u algún otro error, soy novato y recién estoy aprendiendo, necesitaría ayuda, gracias.

```js
<script>
  
   function cambiarImagen() {
  
  
  // 1 - Obtenemos la fecha actual, día y hora
let date = new Date(),
    currentNumberDay = date.getUTCDay(),
    currentHourDay = date.getUTCHours();

    // 2 - Declaramos un objeto con una prop por día, c/u con sus respectivas imágenes por hora
const customImagesPC = {
    "0": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/vZDtwKd/edgardo-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/dk6FHTN/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-45.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/dk6FHTN/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-45.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6P2wbRh/aedion-480-450-px.png"
    ],
    "1": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/GWvMSB7/mc-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/8mScyqm/roma2-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/SPJYZBS/carlos-480-450-px-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg"
    ],
    "2": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/VL5Tg8X/ameliee.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/2YM7jGy/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-49.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png"
    ],
    "3": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/7KMr5QW/missmonique11.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZWg1n6t/NINA-KRAVIk.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/D52jCJP/deborahh11.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/hKWvcXc/EMANUEL2023-480-450-px-3.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/37TMS3V/EMANUEL2023-480-450-px-4.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png"
    ],
    "4": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/VL5Tg8X/ameliee.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/VL5Tg8X/ameliee.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/VL5Tg8X/ameliee.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png"
    ],
    "5": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/7bSkc4F/cristianmadridprog22345.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/mHK3sQ1/Copia-de-ABRILLIVEPROGRA.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/wry0KBy/rain-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/b36NhVx/PATRIKprograma113.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/FwD0718/portadaprog.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/FwD0718/portadaprog.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      " https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/kKQCZj4/tonyprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png"
    ],
    "6": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/25vQXb6/fernando-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/swBy5Fb/tonynoelive1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/hFfkKK1/daviak-480-450-px.png"
    ]
  }

   // Aquí solo reemplaza tus imagenes que vas a poner si es movil
const customImagesMovil = {
    "0": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/vZDtwKd/edgardo-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/dk6FHTN/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-45.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/dk6FHTN/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-45.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6P2wbRh/aedion-480-450-px.png"
    ],
    "1": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/GWvMSB7/mc-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/8mScyqm/roma2-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/SPJYZBS/carlos-480-450-px-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg"
    ],
    "2": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/VL5Tg8X/ameliee.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/2YM7jGy/Dise-o-sin-t-tulo-49.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png ",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/JyYZ5nB/ceroa200011.png"
    ],
    "3": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/7KMr5QW/missmonique11.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZWg1n6t/NINA-KRAVIk.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/D52jCJP/deborahh11.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/hKWvcXc/EMANUEL2023-480-450-px-3.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/37TMS3V/EMANUEL2023-480-450-px-4.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png"
    ],
    "4": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pWsZFB6/electronic-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/6DMjwbQ/terciario2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/yXzyGSk/secundario-2.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png"
    ],
    "5": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/7bSkc4F/cristianmadridprog22345.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/mHK3sQ1/Copia-de-ABRILLIVEPROGRA.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/wry0KBy/rain-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/b36NhVx/PATRIKprograma113.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/FwD0718/portadaprog.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/FwD0718/portadaprog.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      " https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/kKQCZj4/tonyprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/37TMS3V/EMANUEL2023-480-450-px-4.png"
    ],
    "6": [
      "https://i.ibb.co/25vQXb6/fernando-480-450-px.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/swBy5Fb/tonynoelive1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/pXkv1wB/portadaprog-1.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/ZMHSMKB/ceroa20001.png",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/NZDRd6N/djsclubliveportada250921.jpg",
      "https://i.ibb.co/hFfkKK1/daviak-480-450-px.png"
    ]
  }

    /* 3 - Esta función solamente obtendrá los valores de la propiedad [X] que la pasemos por parámetro
    * Accede a la prop 0,1,2,3 según sea el caso
    * Accede a la posición de la prop 0,1,2 etc para obtener el nombre de imagen por hora.
    * NOTA: Se agrega una validación para saber de donde tomar los recursos, si es movil o no.
    */
let getImage = (numberDay, currentHour, isMovil) =>{
    const getImageByDay = isMovil ? customImagesMovil[numberDay] : customImagesPC[numberDay] 
    return getImageByDay[currentHour]; 
}

    /* 4 - Esta función cada X tiempo (60 seg) ejecutará la función getImage() para obtener la url
    *      y mediante un callback (Función que se ejecuta después de haberse ejecutado una anteriormente)
    *      devolverá la url.
    */

let executeInterval = (isMovil, callback) =>{
    setInterval(() =>{
        callback(getImage(currentNumberDay, currentHourDay, isMovil))
    }, 2000); // Cambiar timer a 60 seg.
}



    /* 5 - En este punto seteamos al cargar la página una imagen según la hora y día, 
    *      seguido ejecutamos la función executeInterval() pasando como parámetro una función para recuperar el valor del intervalo
    *      y setearlo cada x tiempo al atributo src de tu tag imagen.
    */
let setImage = (isMovil) => {
    document.getElementById("fullwidth").src = getImage(currentNumberDay, currentHourDay, isMovil)

    executeInterval(isMovil, newUrl => {
        console.log("New URL and TAG", document.getElementById("fullwidth").src = newUrl)
        document.getElementById("fullwidth").src = newUrl
    })
}


    /* 6 - Aquí solo hacemos comparación para saber si estamos en un movil o no, posterior a eso ejecutamos la funcion setImage()
     * pasando como parametro un bool (true o false) segun sea el caso, si es true obtiene las imagagenes del objeto customImagesMovil,
     * caso contrario si es false obtiene la imagen de customImagesPC
     */

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)  || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {
    // console.log("Phone");
    setImage(true)
} else {
    // console.log("No Phone");
    setImage(false)
}
    
   }
   cambiarImagen();  
   setInterval(cambiarImagen, 1000);
    
  
  

 
</script>
```